# Set a Loader with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, loader

I am trying to set a loader in my React webapp but this is the error that constantly is shown:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in RegistrazioneBici (at App.js:31)
    in Route (at App.js:27)
    in div (at App.js:24)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:22)
```

I have my App component that containes all the possible routes.

```
const App = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      {loading === false ? (
        <>
          <Router>
            <Navbar2 />
            <div className="containerApp">
              <Route path="/" exact render={(props) => <Home />} />
             
              <Route
                path="/registrazionebici"
                exact
                render={(props) => (
                  <RegistrazioneBici
                    loading={loading}
                    setLoading={setLoading}
                    {...props}
                  />
                )}
              />        
              <Route
                path="/adminnotarizzazione"
                exact
                render={(props) => <Admin setLoading={setLoading} {...props} />}
              />
            </div>
            <Separatore color={"#eee"} />
            <Footer />
          </Router>
        </>
      ) : (
        <Loader />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

and this is the code for RegistrationBici.js during the form submit:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setModalShow(false);
    setHashCampi("");
    
    const isValid = await controllaCampi(); //validation of the fields
    if (isValid) {
      // setLoader(true);
      props.setLoading(true);

      responseHash = await eseguiHash( //hash of the fields
        nome,
        cognome,
        email,
        marca,
        modello,
        telaio
      );
      
      ... other dbcalls ....

      props.setLoading(false);
      setModalShow(true);
    } else {
      console.log("There is an error");
    }
    props.setLoading(false)
  };
```

I tried to add a state locally in Registrazione.js in order to make the error disappear and it works but in this case only the content of the file is overshadowed by the loader and not the Navbar.

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Moreover, that is not an error, that is a warning, that needs to be fixed to avoid the memory leaks, and another question is where is that props.setLoading is coming from, Use useState() hook to update the state. and wrap handleSubmit in useCallback so that it doesn't rerender each time something updates.